# How to properly align content for mobile at the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar designed specifically for mobile devices. It is a side navbar that will fill the whole screen to any device.

I have already tried using stuff like `vw` and `vh` but it messes up depending on the device. Looks fine on my test devices but will not work properly on most other devices.

```css
    body,
html {
  margin: auto 0;
  background-image: url(kees-streefkerk-352781-unsplash.jpg);
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

nav {
  background-color: #222;
  height: 42px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

li a img {
  height: 45px;
  margin-top: -12px;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-left: -45px;
}

.nav-first {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.mobile-button {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mobile-navbar-text {
  display: none;
}

.facebook,
.twitter,
.instagram {
  display: none;
}


/* Mobile */

@media (max-width: 599px) {
  nav {
    height: 64px;
    position: absolute;
  }
  li a img {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    margin-top: 0px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  }
  .navbar-text {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile-navbar-text {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  }
  .mobile-button {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 64px;
    width: 62px;
    margin-top: -16px;
    line-height: 65px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  }
  .mobile-sidenavbar {
    background-color: #222;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }

  .instagram,
  .facebook,
  .twitter {
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  .closebtn {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }

  .media-links {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 38px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}


/* Tablet */

@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  nav {
    height: 64px;
    position: absolute;
  }
  li a img {
    transform: scale(2);
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: -32px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  }
  .navbar-text {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile-navbar-text {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  }
  .mobile-button {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: -13px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  }
  .mobile-sidenavbar {
    background-color: #222;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
  .instagram,
  .facebook,
  .twitter {
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  .closebtn {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 9vw;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }

  .media-links {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 38px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font- 
awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://seeklogo.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/american-flag-logo-vector.png"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-first navbar-text">Sample Text</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-text">Sample Text</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-text">Sample Text</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-text">Sample Text</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-text">Sample Text</a></li>
      <span class="mobile-button">&#9776;</span>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="mobile-sidenavbar">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn">&times;</a>
    <a href="#" class="mobile-navbar-text">Sample Text</a>
    <a href="#" class="mobile-navbar-text">Sample Text</a>
    <a href="#" class="mobile-navbar-text">Sample Text</a>
    <a href="#" class="mobile-navbar-text">Sample Text</a>
    <a href="#" class="mobile-navbar-text">Sample Text</a>
<div class="media-links">
    <a href="#" class="fa facebook">&#xf082;</a>
    <a href="#" class="fa twitter">&#xf081;</a>
    <a href="#" class="fa instagram">&#xf16d;</a>
</div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="masterjs.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mobile-button').on('click touchend', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('.mobile-sidenavbar').css({'width': 100 + '%',});
  });
  $('.closebtn').on('click touchend', function() {
    $('.mobile-sidenavbar').css({'width': 0 + '%',});
  });
});</script>
</body>
```

That code should be all that is needed to replicate the problem if not let me know. I would like the Facebook, Instagram, and Twitter icons to be at the bottom of the navbar no matter the size of the device or what device. An example is on my iPhone X it looks perfect but I am using google chromes device simulator in the dev console on iPhone 5/SE it is off the screen. Please help. Thank You.

Comment: Your code , *as is*, is not showing any social media icons, I see the classes, but I don't see the icons, don't you have to include a library for the icons?

Comment: @IvanS95 Yes i forgot to add that thank you i will add them now.

Comment: @IvanS95 they should be there now. I also forgot to add the JS so it should be there now. That is my bad im working outside at the same time.

Comment: Still can't see them; inspecting the console it seems the snippet is not able to find the CSS for font-awesome and can't find `master.js`

Comment: @IvanS95 I am seeing the same thing. I'm not sure why it is not loading them. It is a link so it should be pulling from the link because i do not have it saved as a file on my computer. Everything else is working except for that. The ```masterjs.js``` is the file i have on my computer so i took the code from there and added it in a script tag in the HTML so that should be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Alright; after battling for a while with libraries, queries and properties, I finally made it work.

I really recommend you read the code carefully so you fully grasp the changes I made.

Most important, I removed the absolute positioning you defined for the icons, grouped them together and made their container a flex-container. Absolute position is not really necessary for this and also causes a lot of awkward and inconsistent behavior like what you had before; I also removed the `transform: scale(3)` property you had, since that caused the icons to increase in size without increasing the size of the container, thus overflowing it and overlapping other items.

I instead increased their `font-size`, which is what should be altered to make them look bigger, they are font icons after all.

Also, the margins you defined using `vh` and `vw` units were too big, you should avoid those as well; so I removed them.

Again, read carefully and compare with your code, hopefully I helped you; you should take a look at **Flexbox**
, it'll help you a lot as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mobile-button').on('click touchend', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('.mobile-sidenavbar').css({
      'width': 100 + '%',
    });
  });
  $('.closebtn').on('click touchend', function() {
    $('.mobile-sidenavbar').css({
      'width': 0 + '%',
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: auto 0;
  background-image: url(kees-streefkerk-352781-unsplash.jpg);
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

nav {
  background-color: #222;
  height: 42px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

li a img {
  height: 45px;
  margin-top: -12px;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-left: -45px;
}

.nav-first {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.mobile-button {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mobile-navbar-text {
  display: none;
}

.facebook,
.twitter,
.instagram {
  display: none;
}


/* Mobile */

@media (max-width: 599px) {
  nav {
    height: 64px;
    position: absolute;
  }
  li a img {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    margin-top: 0px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  }
  .navbar-text {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile-navbar-text {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  }
  .mobile-button {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 64px;
    width: 62px;
    margin-top: -16px;
    line-height: 65px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  }
  .mobile-sidenavbar {
    background-color: #222;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
  .facebook {
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .twitter {
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .instagram {
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .closebtn {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  
  .media-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 38px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/* Tablet */

@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  nav {
    height: 64px;
    position: absolute;
  }
  li a img {
    transform: scale(2);
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: -32px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  }
  .navbar-text {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile-navbar-text {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  }
  .mobile-button {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: -13px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  }
  .mobile-sidenavbar {
    background-color: #222;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
  .facebook,
  .twitter,
  .instagram {
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    font-size: 38px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .closebtn {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 9vw;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
  .media-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 38px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://seeklogo.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/american-flag-logo-vector.png"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-first navbar-text">Sample Text</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-text">Sample Text</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-text">Sample Text</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-text">Sample Text</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-text">Sample Text</a></li>
      <span class="mobile-button">&#9776;</span>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="mobile-sidenavbar">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn">&times;</a>
    <a href="#" class="mobile-navbar-text">Sample Text</a>
    <a href="#" class="mobile-navbar-text">Sample Text</a>
    <a href="#" class="mobile-navbar-text">Sample Text</a>
    <a href="#" class="mobile-navbar-text">Sample Text</a>
    <a href="#" class="mobile-navbar-text">Sample Text</a>
    <div class="media-links">
      <a href="#" class="fa facebook">&#xf082;</a>
      <a href="#" class="fa twitter">&#xf081;</a>
      <a href="#" class="fa instagram">&#xf16d;</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Ok thank you. I will review this soon because I am really busy at the moment.

Comment: Instead of ```flex``` I added ```inline-flex``` and instead of ```justify-content: center``` I added a ```<center></center>``` tag around ```media-links``` and it all flows nicely and stays off the screen except its not centering properly. It is centered but a little off to the right. Anyway to fix this?

Comment: The `<center>` tag is deprecated in HTML5, you should not use it... was it giving you issues the way I have it in the example?

Comment: Yes. When I remove ```<center>``` it's at the bottom where I want it except all the way to the left and I want it perfectly centered just like the text.

Comment: You sure? If I run the snippet the icons are centered, that's why I use justify-content: center

Comment: Yes. When I use ```display: flex, justify-content: center``` it causes the icons to appear on the page outside of the navbar. When I use ```inline-flex``` it stays inside the navbar. It's just when that happens it causes the icons to be all the way to the left basically "stuck" to the left side. That is why i tried using ```center```.

Comment: I've tried using ```margin-left``` and it works just when it gets to a bigger screened device it's off-centered again because the pixels used for the first device size is smaller.

Comment: Try using margin: 0 auto

Comment: Did not do anything.

Comment: It's odd, I don't see any of the issues you describe on the snippet, maybe there's something on your local files affecting it?

Comment: There should not be. I had to modify the code you edited because mine for what ever reason will not show the icons. But I did it exactly like mine to show how the icons are sticking like I'm describing

Comment: @Cody where you able to get it working? If possible, try editing your question and add another snippet just copying and pasting the code you are trying right now that is giving you the issues, that way I can take a look at it and find the problem

Comment: @Cody now I understand, I didn't understand before that you wanted the media icons to be at the bottom of the whole page, not just as the last items on the menu, the reason why they don't align center when you add the `position: absolute` is because they stop using the full width of the page; you just need to add `width: 100%` and your problem will be gone, look at the snippet again in full screen

Comment: I will try adding that later today. But the way I had it last night when I put the device into landscape mode the icons went over the text because it was set to bottom: 0. So do to this I might just remove it and put them somewhere else

Comment: @Cody the reason for that is simply that in landscape orientation, depending on the screen size, there's not enough available space to show all the items, and position absolute causes the item to be on top of everything else; that's why I suggested avoiding it, another option you can try is sticking with Flexbox to position this element at the bottom, but using a scrollbar in landscape mode to be able to scroll to the bottom icons... If there's not enough space on the screen you simply have to compromise a few things

Comment: How would I go about making it scrollable to be able to do that only for devices put into landscape?

Comment: I did what you said and took away ```position: absolute``` and added ```width: 100%``` and it works fine just now cannot figure out a way to get it to the bottom and the icons are messed up now. Here is a screen shot of the way the icons are acting. https://imgur.com/a/GUzoxfw

Comment: I found its the ```width: 100%``` causing it to look like that

Comment: I found that using ```position: absolute``` with ```width: 100vw``` causes it to fit at the bottom exactly in the middle without going off the navbar.